# How to access XCUIElement under one particular view but the view may in different application in Swift?

Tags: swift

I would like to access one XCUIElement button, "OK" that's is under one view. However the view may pop under different application how can I do it? I do not want to double the view and set them under different napplication

```
var okButton {
    app.viewA.button["ok"]
}
```